# is it possible to decrease the length of base64 string of type image in flutter?

Tags: flutter, api, dart, post, base64

I am sending an image as base64 string to API through post function and getting errors like;

The requested URL is over the maximum size allowed

statusCode: 414

414 Request-URI Too Large

The function I am using

```
getAndUploadProfilePicture() async {
    final _picker = ImagePicker();

    final XFile? pickedImage = await _picker.pickImage(
      source: ImageSource.gallery,
      imageQuality: 20,
    );
    if (pickedImage != null) {
      file = File(pickedImage.path);
      final bytes = File(pickedImage.path).readAsBytesSync();

      String img64 = base64Encode(bytes);

      try {
        Dio dio = ApiServices().launch();

        final response = await dio.post(EndPoints.uploadUserProfilePicture,
            queryParameters: {"id": '24', "picture": img64, "type": 'guide'});

        if (response.statusCode == 200) {
          print('picture upload successfullyy');
          print(response.statusMessage);
        }
      } catch (e, s) {
        // ignore: avoid_print

        print("DatabaseService getAndUploadProfilePicture() Exception: $e");
        // ignore: avoid_print
        print(s);
      }
    } else {}
  }
```

The API call work fine when i pass a small dummy string instead of base64 image

Answer (score 1):

You cannot decrease the length of a base64-encoded string for an image without first resizing or recompressing the image to be smaller or without corrupting the image by truncating its data.  However, that's the wrong question to ask to fix your problem.

If you're making a request via an http POST operation, you shouldn't be passing the image data through `queryParameters` (which are encoded into the URL itself, hence the error about the URI being too long).  You should be supplying it through `dio.post`'s `data` argument instead. [`package:dio`'s `README.md`](https://pub.dev/packages/dio) shows an example for using `dio.post`:

> Performing a POST request:
>
> ```dart
> response = await dio.post('/test', data: {'id': 12, 'name': 'wendu'});
> ```